# Como adicionar um segundo eixo Y utilizando a função matplot?

Tags: r, gráfico

Tenho duas séries de dados com escalas diferentes e gostaria de plotar as duas em um mesmo gráfico, a segunda é a derivada da primeira. Estou utilizando o código abaixo, mas ele não funciona da forma que desejo, pois plota os dados com apenas um eixo Y.  Queria adicionar um segundo eixo Y, de preferência do lado direito do gráfico. Qual a solução?

```
matplot(dataTGA$V1,
    cbind(dataTGA$V3, dataDTGA$V3), 
    xlab = "Temperatura (K)",
    ylab = "Perda de massa (%)",
    type= "l")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar a função `axis` para adicionar um eixo extra ao gráfico e se necessário `mtext` para colocar seu label. Por exemplo, para um gráfico simples:

```
par(mar = c(5, 4, 4, 4) + 0.1)
plot(1:10, ylab = "Eixo Y Esquerdo")
lines(10:1)
axis(4, at = 1:10, labels = seq(10, 100, 10))
mtext("Eixo Y Direito", side = 4, line = 2)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que você tem que ajustar a margem direita com `par` e que você pode colocar valores diferentes da posição real no eixo utilizando o argumento `labels`.

Se os dados forem de escalas diferentes e você preferir não transformar os dados do segundo eixo, pode usar a seguinte forma:

```
par(mar = c(5, 4, 2, 4) + 0.1)
plot(1:10, ylab = "Eixo Y Esquerdo")
par(new = TRUE, mar = c(5, 4, 2, 4) + 0.1)
plot(100:1, type = "l", axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "")
axis(4, at = seq(0, 100, 10), labels = seq(0, 100, 10))
mtext("Eixo Y Direito", side = 4, line = 2)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Neste caso o argumento `new = TRUE` de `par` faz com que a área gráfica não seja "limpa" quando você chama a função `plot` novamente. Fique atento que a partir deste momento os eixos serão relativos aos valores de `x` e `y` do segundo gráfico.

Vários exemplos e alternativas (com funções de outros pacotes) estão disponíveis numa [pergunta similar do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142944/how-can-i-plot-with-2-different-y-axes).

Comment: o problema é que a segunda série tem uma escala diferente da primeira, dessa forma eu teria de "transformar" os dados para que fiquem adequados para serem plotados nessa segunda escala. O que preciso é uma forma de plotar duas series em diferentes escalas em uma mesma área. O produto que quero é semelhante a essa imagem:
http://www.chamotlabs.com/ApplicationNotes/HTC/WoodTGA.gif

Comment: @RodrigoSimetti Editei a resposta com uma solução para dados em escalas diferentes.

Comment: Perfeito, @Molx. Exatamente isso.

Answer (score -1):

E no caso de eu usar barplot ou boxplot para ambas as variávies? Qual argumento eu devo usar para que os plots não fiquem sobrepostos?